# Windows 7 programs corruption

Tags: windows-7

Some of the software like iTunes, real player, Google earth is missing from my computer. Desktop short cut remains same, but the actual program files content is either missing or not opening from the exec file from program files. There is only one system restore point generated by the system 3 days ago and restoring to restore point didn't help. But other programs like mac fee, M YOB, office is working fine. I scanned the system with built-in updated Mac fee and virus scanner of bit defender and kaspersky and no viruses were detected. Please help

Comment: [`chkdsk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK)`C: /F` is a good place to start.

Comment: Can you find the software in your `%ProgramFiles%` folder?

Comment: Yes. But not all of them. Some of the corrupted programs from the program files are missing and others are in program file. But if I click on exe file, nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for the chkdsk tip. I am checking this now and will let you know once its completed.

Comment: Chkdsk C:/F didn't return any error. Thanks

Comment: Try a search through the root of your drive for the binaries of the missing programs (e.g. itunes.exe). They may have been moved somehow. If that doesn't work, and your HD is fine, look suspiciously at your spouse/children/other possible users of your computer :)

Answer (score 1):

Check **Programs and Features** in ***Control Panel*** to see whether these missing programs are still installed or not.

Other user could have uninstalled them.

Also ***check timestamps of directories remaining after programs***. Directory timestamp is modified when content of directory is changed. This could give you an idea about last date of manipulation with these program directories.